# Incorrect region file reading with halcon

Tags: c#, halcon

I have a C# Windows Form application which uses halcon file to process some images. In the program, I want to read region object, which was saved in the specific directory, and use it as parameter. When I start to program, program automatically reads region from directory. When I trigger to program for processing image, it uses that region as a parameter. But I have a problem at that point. Region size is different from the original region file. When I read that file again without closing program, it is seen it's original size. How can I solve that problem? How can I read that region correctly at first?

This is how I read region from directory

```
HOperatorSet.ReadRegion(out parentForm.region, path + "_Region.hobj");
```

This is how I use region as parameter.

```
hDevProcedureCall.SetInputIconicParamObject("Region", parentForm.region);
```

This is how I start process

```
hDevProcedureCall.Execute();
```

When program starts, region is seen like that (orange rectangular). But it's original size is bigger than shampoo

[image]

Comment: Could you upload your Region.hobj?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fZgFOcUnFyfuyhAualy-Q2ETPIhzrPcd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right region in C# program? Can you inspect the region parameters like area and starting row and column?

Comment: Actually I read region, when program starts. When program starts, values are 9075, 90 and 67 (area,row,column). When I read region again with button, values change to 229042, 232, 325.5 respectively. Region reading function is totally same. I mean, I am sure that I read same file with same codes. There is one more confusing situation. When I read same file from Halcon's own program, Values are seen as 181295, 232 and 259.  @VladimirPerković

Comment: Is your clip_region setting set to false? 
    set_system ('clip_region', 'false')

Comment: Yeap, that is it. It solved problem. Awesome!! Thanks!!!